# How to resolve HTTP Version Not Supported or StatusCode=505 error?

Tags: apex, callout

```
18:05:15.047 (47002596)|CALLOUT_REQUEST|
[217]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://rest1.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-
services/32qip/search/Candidate?BhRestToken=5a9c3e65-bad6-45c7-91d3-
14b1f9452fd8&query=dateLastModified:[20150601 TO 
20150608]&fields=id,firstName,lastName,address,dateLastModified&count=1&sor
t=dateLastModified, Method=GET]
```

Comment: can u explain what you are trying to do and when you get this error. and may be sharing your code will help us as well to answer

Comment: [HTTP Error 505 - HTTP version not supported](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E505.html). However, the error code could be misleading see e.g. [HTTP error code 505](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734205/http-error-code-505).

Comment: Yes, it was weird error. When I tested the same endpoint in rurl and Chome REST API, I got error but when I included that in APEX code. It errored out. After some digging I found that SPACES needs to be replaced with +.

Answer (score 0):

Error code was at [20150601 TO 20150608]
Replaced with [20150601+TO+20150608] which resolved the error.

System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://rest1.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-
services/32qip/search/Candidate?BhRestToken=5a9c3e65-bad6-45c7-91d3-
14b1f9452fd8&query=dateLastModified:[20150601 TO 
20150608]&fields=id,firstName,lastName,address,dateLastModified&count=1&sor
t=dateLastModified, Method=GET]